# Using Lua to format section titles

Tags: luatex, context, lua

I'm trying to create a new `lecture` environment from the base `section` one.

I'd like its title to be `Lecture <number>: <title>` if a title is provided, and `Lecture <number>` if it isn't. This title should also be reported in the left footer.

This is the code I have so far:

```tex
\definehead
  [lecture]
  [section]

\setuphead
  [lecture]
  [
    command=\Lecture,
    style=\bfc,
  ]

\setuplabeltext
  [lecture={Lecture}]

\define[2]\Lecture{\ctxlua{
  userdata.format_lecture_title({
    label = context.labeltext('lecture'),
    number = [==[#1]==],
    title = [==[#2]==],
  })
}}

\setupfootertexts
  [\ctxlua{
    userdata.format_lecture_title({
      label = context.labeltext('lecture'),
      number = context.getmarking({'lecturenumber'}),
      title = context.getmarking({'lecture'}),
    })
  }]
  [pagenumber]

\startluacode
  userdata = userdata or {}

  function userdata.format_lecture_title(args)
    if args.title and args.title ~= '' then
      context('%s %s: %s', args.label, args.number, args.title)
    else
      context('%s %s', args.label, args.number)
    end
  end
\stopluacode

\starttext

% Both title and left footer should be 'Lecture 1: Foo'
\startlecture [title={Foo}]
Foo bar baz
\stoplecture

\page

% Both title and left footer should be 'Lecture 2'
\startlecture []
Foo bar baz
\stoplecture

\stoptext
```

Unfortunately neither the title in the body nor the one in the footer are reported correctly. The former is formatted simply as `Lecture`:

[image]

while the latter is formatted as `Lecture<number><title>`:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following could likely be improved but seems to do what you need:

```
\definehead
  [lecture]
  [section]

\setuplabeltext[lecture=Lecture~]

\setuphead
  [lecture]
  [placehead=yes, bodypartlabel=lecture, command=\Lecture]

\define[2]\Lecture{%
  \doiftextelse{#2}{#1: #2}{#1}
}

\define\LectureFooter{%
  \doiftextelse
    {\headtextcontent}
    {\headnumbercontent: \headtextcontent}
    {\headnumbercontent}
}

\setupfootertexts
  [\LectureFooter]
  [pagenumber]


\starttext

% Both title and left footer should be 'Lecture 1: Foo'
\startlecture [title={Foo}]
Foo bar baz
\stoplecture

\page

% Both title and left footer should be 'Lecture 2'
\startlecture []
Foo bar baz
\stoplecture

\stoptext
```

As for how this works... Well having the `Lecture` part in your title comes directly from the Wiki section on `\setuphead` (https://www.contextgarden.net/Command/setuphead), specifically the "Setting label of a part" section. I then looked up `\setuplabeltext` directly (https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/_setuplabeltext) and found an example of how the `command` option of `setuphead` actually works. The first argument is the number and the second is the title of your section. Which means that all you need is just a simple if statement that you can accomplish without Lua.

Since your Lua code was running, I then used `inspect` to see what the contents of your args table was. It turned out that it was not sending direct values of lecture name but the context commands `\headnumbercontent` and `\headtextcontent`, which I pulled out and used directly in the footer. This also explains why your Lecture 1 was showing up under Lecture 2. The `\headtextcontent` wouldn't have changed yet when `command` was issued... You can see the effect by changing `command` to `before` in your code.